# How I call vb Code in javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

```
 function DownloadImage() { 
     var imagepath=  $("input[id$=hdn_Downloadpath]").val()

        <% Dim filePath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Convention_IagesPath") & "images/"%> + imagepath.ToString()

        <%  Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"%>

        <%  Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & filePath & """")%>

        <% Response.TransmitFile(filePath)%>

        <% Response.End()%>

}
```

How I cal vb Code in java script. there are also one more issue is when page is call then this code also execute and due to that it generate error

Comment: Youll need to preform an ajax request to a method on the server as javascript is executed on the client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. Javascript is client side and VB is server side. You'll need to find a way to call the server back, by doing a post/get or ajax.

In your case, you could have your javascript like this

```
function DownloadImage() { 
    var imagepath=  $("input[id$=hdn_Downloadpath]").val()

    window.location="some_page.aspx?imagePath=" + imagepath;
}
```

And have a page, called some_page.aspx with this code

```
Dim filePath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Convention_IagesPath") & "images/" + Request.QueryString("imagePath")

Response.ContentType = "image/jpg"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" & filePath & """")
Response.TransmitFile(filePath)
Response.End()
```

* This is an example